# non-linear system with eigenvalue zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-system, jacobian

I'm wondering what happens if you have a non-linear system and you solve it by calculating the eigenvalues of the Jacobian, what happens when one eigenvalue is 0?

Do you have then for example when the other one is positive something like straight lines trough the initial value of the one with the zero value diverging for the other one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A nonlinear continuous time system with an equilibrium whose Jacobian has an eigenvalue with real part zero (and no eigenvalues with positive real part) can't be assessed using linear theory; the behavior near that equilibrium is "sensitive to nonlinear details".

Comment: But when you have other nonzero eigenvalues what happens then?

Comment: If they have negative real part, then that doesn't make any difference. If they have positive real part, then the equilibrium is still unstable.

Comment: wait so when you have a zero eigenvalue and a positive one it's unstable and when you hev a zero and a negative its stable?

Comment: and how would a phase portrait look?

Comment: Zero and positive = unstable. Zero and negative = ambiguous (in the nonlinear case). In the linear case, zero and negative = stable.

Comment: https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/wiki/images/f/f3/Cds140a-wi11-Week5NotesCMT.pdf